# pstricks, auto-pst-pdf and arXiv

Tags: pstricks, shell-escape, arxiv

I tried to submit a LaTeX file to arXiv. It failed and gave me this error message:

```
! Package auto-pst-pdf Error:
"shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
auto-pst-pdf will not work!
.

See the auto-pst-pdf package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.134 Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}
%
?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.134 Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}
%
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

In the past, I could upload to arXiv files with PSTricks code with no problem. What happened?

UPDATE (2019): Previously there was a workaround – one could submit a paper without `\includegraphics` commands and then the `auto-pst-pdf` would not check for the `--shell-escape` flag. But now, arXiv have moved to TeXLive 2016, which always checks for the `--shell-escape` flag. So now this workaround does not work.

What can I do? Should I convert every single `pspicture` (I have many) to a `.png` file? Or is there an easier solution?

SECOND UPDATE: I asked the staff at arXiv, and they suggested that I just comment out the line "\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}". I did it, and indeed without this line, the file compiles fine on arXiv. However, without this line it does not compile on my computer - I get errors "Undefined control sequence" on \psframe. This is strange since I have TeXLive 2016, just like arXiv. How can I make my file compile without auto-pst-pdf?

Comment: I suppose that they are using `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`. In such a case you do not need the `auto-pst-pdf` package.